# I cant access API in Sails JS Web Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sails.js

I have created tesApp Using "sails new test-project" > Selected "Web App".

My question is how can I access api endpoints in Postman ?

I do not see any tokens in request header.

Comment: This is a confusing question. Are you asking how to simply call a local api, or adding authorization to one? Or how to use Postman?

Comment: My question js how can I access local api in Sails ?

Comment: I still don't think that makes your question any easier to decipher. Have you read the sails documentation? Use the ponzicoder video tutorials on YouTube? Simply just created a new sails application and wondering what do I do next?...